# Unable to use sub queries sql with single table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query one network packets table using mysql. But I am not able use sub query using sql. Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE netpacket IF NOT EXISTS
(src_port INT,
 status STRING);
```

This is how my first 5 records of table (There are 17k records):

```
 --------------------------
| src_port |  status       |
 --------------------------
|   53     |  active       |
 --------------------------
|   4321   |  active       |
 --------------------------
|   53     |   active      |
 ---------------------------
|   8000   |  running      |
 --------------------------
|   8721   |  idle         |
 --------------------------
|   8000   |  running      |
 --------------------------
|    21    |  connected    |
 --------------------------
|    53    | disconnected  |
 --------------------------  
|    53    |  disconnected |
 --------------------------
|    53    |  active       |
 --------------------------
```

There are five status in the given table(Namely *active*, *disconnected*, *connected*, *idle*, *running*).

Now what I am trying to do is, I want the count and number of src_port along with it's status like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------  
|    src_port    |  src_port_count    |  status       |
 -----------------------------------------------------
|    8000        |       2            |  running      |
 -----------------------------------------------------
|    53          |       2            |  disconnected |
 -----------------------------------------------------
|    53          |       3            |  active       |
 -----------------------------------------------------
```

And this what I have tried so far now,

```
select count(src_port) as src_port_count from netpacket where status in (select status from netpacket  where status='running')
```

But only I'm getting error like this

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:60: value and result of subquery must be of the same type for IN expression: integer vs varchar
```

I am not sure about sub query, but is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the count and number of src_port along with it's status

You seem to be looking for a simple aggregate query. I don't see the need for a subuqery here:

```
select src_port, status, count(*) from netpacket group by src_port, status
```

Comment: Okay I tried this query, but its showing me all port which have status and which don't have status. How can I rectify this. Only need to print the ports who has status!!. I tried using null and not null keywords, didn't work. 
Thanks!

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni: do you have `status`es that are `null`? It is not showing in your sample data. You can just add a `where` clause to eliminate those: `select src_port, status, count(*) from netpacket where status is not null group by src_port, status`

Comment: ```is not null``` didn't work, it's showing completely blank column. Instead I used ```<>``` operator and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni: welcome! Ok, so these values are not null, the are empty.